# Integral of $a/b^x$?

Tags: integration

Sorry if very basic but most of my math career is behind me, and I have really given an honest effort at finding this online.

I know the integral of $a^x$ is $a^x / \ln (a)$. But is there a quick way to get the integral when $a^x$ is a denominator?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{a}{{b^x }} = a\big( {\frac{1}{b}} \big)^x$. Apply the rule you know with $1/b$ in place of $a$.

Comment: This might help: $\frac{a}{b^x}=ab^{-x}$.